# Tem como estender o form do admin para minha página?

Tags: python, django

Tenho um form criado e exibido com o admin do jeito que eu quero...porém é um site para preenchimento de cadastro de usuários, então o usuário não tem acesso ao admin, quero que o form do admin seja usado fora dele.

No meu não tá aparecendo os campos de opção, por exemplo que aparecem no form dentro do admin

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
        from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models
from django.db import models


VINCULO = (
    (u'1', u'Bolsista'),
    (u'2', u'Estagiário'),
    (u'3', u'Terceiro'),
    (u'4', u'Servidor'),
    (u'5', u'Aluno Pós-Graduação'),
    (u'6', u'Servidor de outros órgãos'),
    (u'7', u'Professor Colaborador'),
)

SALAS = (
    (u'1', u'SysAdmin'),
    (u'2', u'Help Desk'),
)

RENOVADO = (
    (u'1', u'Sim'),
    (u'2', u'Não'),
)

EMPRESAS = (
    (u'1', u'Cray'),
    (u'2', u'Outra'),
)

TIPO = (
    (u'1', u'Técnico'),
    (u'2', u'Tecnologista'),
)


class Inscricao(models.Model):
        vinculo = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=VINCULO)
        registro = models.IntegerField()
        nome = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
        data_nascimento = models.DateField()
        data_admissao = models.DateField()
        sala = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=SALAS)
        telefone = models.CharField(max_length=30)
        ramal = models.CharField(max_length=30)
        orientador = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        data_fim_contrato = models.DateField()
        renovado = models.CharField(max_length=4, choices=RENOVADO)
        empresa_responsavel = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=EMPRESAS)
        tipo = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=TIPO)
        criado_em = models.DateTimeField('criado em', auto_now_add=True)

        class Meta:
                ordering = ['criado_em']
                verbose_name = (u'nome')
                verbose_name_plural = (u'nomes')

        def __unicode__(self):
                return self.nome
```

Comment: Poste o seu código para que seja mais fácil dar uma sugestão!

Comment: Coloquei  imagem, obrigada pela sugestão

Comment: O Admin, como o nome sugere, foi feito para administradores e/ou desenvolvedores do site, apesar de muita gente usar para tudo (péssima prática). Forms para usuários finais, vc tem que desenvolver os seus próprios. Alguns pacotes como o crispy-forms podem ajudar, veja uma [lista aqui.[(https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/forms/). No momento eu estou utilizando o [django-material.](http://forms.viewflow.io/), Se vc quer preservar o layout original do django-forms (sem o material) opte pelo [crispy-forms.](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo admin do Django, só se o usuário tiver acesso.

Caso queira criar um formulário baseado nas características do seus modelos em um frontend, sugiro utilizar o [Django Forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/#building-a-form-in-django).

Exemplo:

*forms.py*

```
from django import forms

class NameForm(forms.Form):
    your_name = forms.CharField(label='Your name', max_length=100)
```

*template.html*

```
<form action="/your-name/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```